# Is Wifi a broadcast medium?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, tap

If `wifi`/`wlan` is broadcast medium, can we tap the wifi traffic by just placing our `wlan0` into `promiscuous` mode?. In this way, can we get the source ip and destination ip of the traffic generated by other laptops with or without connecting to `AP`?

If `Wifi` is not a broadcast medium, why it is not? I mean, the `router` or `laptop` sending/receiving the singles into/from free space. I answered to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24265/capturing-and-sending-802-11-frames-packets/24266#24266): that software is showing only `beacons` I think!

How wifi works internally and detects the collision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If wifi/wlan is broadcast medium, can we tap the wifi traffic by just
>   placing our wlan0 into promiscuous mode?.

Yes, it is a broadcast medium, in the sense that only one transmitter can be on at a time, and yes, you can sniff Wi-Fi traffic.  The one thing to be aware of is that many Wi-Fi adapter drivers, especially for Windows, can not switch to promiscuous mode.

> How wifi works internally and detects the collision?

Wi-Fi uses CSMA/CA, which is different than Ethernet.  It attemps to avoid collisions from happening. [This question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10715/why-does-wlan-use-collision-avoidance-and-not-collison-detection) explains in more detail.